# Custom extension helper in asp net mvc that return partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, helper

I want to make an extension method in helper, that takes single parameter `partialViewName` and returns partial view as string. I found extension that was used from ASP.NET MVC action as

```
return PartialView("NameOfPartial").ReturnToString();
```

But I want to make it like

```
string partialView = ViewExtensions.RenderToString("NameOfPartial");
```

Reason to make it is that my controller must be `ApiController`, not simple, so it doesn't use `System.Web.Mvc`

Here is a part of code, that I have right now.

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static string RenderToString(string partialViewName)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("An HTTP context is required to render the partial view to a string");
        }

        var controllerName = "Home"; // httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var controller = (ControllerBase)ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, controllerName);

        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, controller);

        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName).View;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                view.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, view, null, null, tw), tw);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Maybe someone knows better how to make it easier, better and also work?

P.S This code snippet returns exception and also, my partialview is in `Shared` folder (basic ASP.NET MVC structure).

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation that we often use.

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var view = viewName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(view))
        {
            view = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, view);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks simple and nice, but what reference do I miss, ViewData and TempData are not defined in current context? Also I want to use it in helper class as ant static extension method.

Comment: You need System.IO and System.Web.Mvc as references.

Comment: If you want to make it an static extension method it signature would look something like this:
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string viewName, object model){
}

Comment: Actually no, this does not work for me. As a static class it does not know what is ControllerContext "the type is not valid in the given context". Also ViewData , TempData are not defined. Furthermore, I use ApiController Action and I try to use this helper, this makes it difficult, because ApiController does not use system.web.mvc, so I believe this is the main reason why I get those errors.

Answer (score -1):

Refer below implementation:

ViewEngineResult viewEngResult = null;

viewEngResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext context, PartialViewPath);

var engineView = viewEngResult.View;